# How to Upload CSV File to SharePointOnline using Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

In my sharepoint list I added "title","author" and company. Then, I try to import my csv file to my sharepoint list and I'm facing the following error:

```
Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are trying to update may 
be read only."
At C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\UploadCSV.ps1:36 char:5
+     $Context.ExecuteQuery()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : XmlException
```

Here is my code snippet:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"  
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"  

#Variables for Processing
$SiteUrl = "https://tenant.com/sites/TeamSite/"
$ListName="Contacts"
$ImportFile ="c:\Scripts\test.csv"
$UserName="xxx@tenant.com"
$Password ="password"

#Setup Credentials to connect
$Credential = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,(ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force))

#Set up the context
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl) 
$Context.Credentials = $credential

#Get the List
$List = $Context.web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)

#Get the Data from CSV and Add to SharePoint List
$data = Import-Csv $ImportFile
Foreach ($row in $data) {

    #add item to List
    $ListItemInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation
    $Item = $List.AddItem($ListItemInfo)
    $Item["Author"] = $row.Author
    $Item["Company"] = $row.Company
    $Item.Update()
    $Context.ExecuteQuery() 

}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @MatthewDoyle Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are trying to update may 
be read only."

Answer (score 0):

Author is a System Person filed, if in CSV file, the Author is user name like "user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com", this is not available to set directly.
Modify Foreach loop like this:

```
$data = Import-Csv $ImportFile

    Foreach ($row in $data) {

        #add item to List
        $ListItemInfo = New-Object 
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation
        $Item = $List.AddItem($ListItemInfo)
        $User = $Context.Web.EnsureUser($row.Author)
        $Context.Load($user)
        $Item["Title"]="New Item Added"
        $Item["Author"] = $user
        $Item["Company"] = $row.Company
        $Item.Update()
        $Context.ExecuteQuery() 

    }
```